# Telerik RadChart axis non-alignment issue

Tags: charts, telerik, alignment, axis, radchart

I am trying to make a bar chart using Telerik RadChart.
I have an issue where the labels are not aligning correctly with the bar charts.
Here is a picture to show what I mean.

[image]

As you can see the labels start before the bar chart.
Here is the code that I think is not working correctly.

```
QueryReportBarChartHTML.PlotArea.XAxis.Items.Add(queryReportData.ElementAt(i).Key.ToString() + "<br/> <p style=\"VISIBILITY: hidden\"><claims>" + queryReporData.ElementAt(i).Value + "</claims></p>");
```

Appreciate any help with this thanks!

Comment: We need more details about the chart.  Can you post a snippet of code that recreates the formatting of the chart with some sample data?

Comment: It's all good. Just needed to add a <center> tag over the label. Just weird as the table was created basically the same as another one without the center tag and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding a  tag over the label.
Weird that it worked as another table created nearly the exact same didn't have the center tag and worked fine.